# SSRS Joining datasets on multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm new to using SSRS, and kind of  understand how to join two datasets using the lookup expression but am having a hard time. My data sets look similar to the below:

`DataSet1 - Sales
Part       Location      Transaction_date         QTY_SOLD`

`DataSet2 - Returns
Part       Location      Transaction_date         QTY_RTS`

Dataset 1 is SQL Server, Dataset 2 is Oracle. I'm get this:

`Part | Location | Transaction_date | QTY_SOLD | QTY RTS`

But I need to join the datasets on part, location, and transaction_date and I'm having trouble joining the two datasets on more than one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to lookup the quantity from the second dataset:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Part.Value + Fields!Location.Value + Fields!Transaction_date.Value
  , Fields!Part.Value + Fields!Location.Value + Fields!Transaction_date.Value
  , Fields!QTY_RTS.Value
  , "Dataset2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept tinkering and answered this myself. Just had to use  between values I want to join on.